Can Guru be younger than oneself?
Are there any instances in scriptures where Guru was younger than disciple? Especially when both were of same varna.

Yes, as per manusmṛti book II :

brāhmasya janmanaḥ kartā svadharmasya ca śāsitā | bālo'pi vipro vṛddhasya pitā bhavati dharmataḥ || 150 ||
That brāhmaṇa who is the giver of the birth for the sake of the veda and the teacher of the prescribed duties becomes by law the father
of an aged man, even though he himself be a child. || 150 ||
adhyāpayāmāsa pitṝn śiśurāṅgirasaḥ kaviḥ | putrakā iti hauvāca jñānena parigṛhya tān || 151 ||
Young kavi, the son of āṅgirasa, taught his (relatives who were old enough to be) fathers, and, as he excelled them in (sacred)
knowledge, he called them 'Little sons.' || 151 ||
te tamarthamapṛcchanta devānāgatamanyavaḥ | devāścaitān sametyaucurnyāyyaṃ vaḥ śiśuruktavān || 152 ||
They, moved with resentment, asked the gods concerning that matter, and the gods, having assembled, answered, 'The child has addressed you
properly.'  || 152 ||
ajño bhavati vai bālaḥ pitā bhavati mantradaḥ | ajñaṃ hi bālamityāhuḥ pitetyeva tu mantradam || 153 ||
'For (a man) destitute of (sacred) knowledge is indeed a child, and he who teaches him the veda is his father; for (the sages) have always
said "child" to an ignorant man, and "father" to a teacher of the
veda.'  || 153 ||
na hāyanairna palitairna vittena na bandhubhiḥ | ṛṣayaścakrire dharmaṃ yo'nūcānaḥ sa no mahān || 154 ||
Neither by years, nor by grey hair, nor by wealth, nor by relatives (is greatness attained); since the sages have made the law that ‘he
who teaches is the greatest among us.’  || 154 ||


Yes.
Siva's son Murugan teaches him the meaning of "Om" or the Pranava Mantra.  The question
Was Lord Muruga Guru to Lord Shiva and taught him the complete explanation of OM?
has this answer
https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/54910/12489 that links to the skanda purana

While his son was speaking in such a manner, Lord Shiva kissed him again, picked him in his lap and while hugging him, with desire, told him, “Speak the meaning of the mantra in my ear.” Then saluting his father with extreme joy, Senani spoke the meaning of the Pranava in secret

It os also the Sthala Puranam of the Swaminath swami temple
https://www.omspiritualshop.com/blogs/news/arulmigu-swaminathaswamy-temple-swamimalai?srsltid=AfmBOorIPK1ZTvcr2FSXcp6dfZuAAa9yz_nkIdVEAcNvNXI9aAo0yHrA

Legend of Swamimalai Temple


According to legend, Swamimalai is the sacred site where an extraordinary event unfolded—a moment of divine instruction that elevated Murugan to the status of a supreme teacher.


As per Hindu legend, Brahma, the god of creation, disrespected Muruga (the son of Shiva) when he visited Mount Kailash, Shiva’s abode. The young Muruga got angry and asked Brahma how he was creating living beings. Brahma replied that he used the Vedas (Hindu scriptures) for creation. Muruga then asked Brahma to recite the Vedas. When Brahma began with the Pranava Mantra, "Om," Muruga stopped him and asked for the meaning of the mantra. Brahma couldn't answer, so Muruga punished and imprisoned him, taking over the role of the creator.


The Devas (celestial deities) were worried about Brahma’s absence and requested Vishnu to intervene. When Vishnu couldn’t help, Shiva himself approached Muruga for Brahma's release. Muruga refused, explaining that Brahma was ignorant of the meaning of the Pranava Mantra. Shiva then asked Muruga to explain it, and Muruga enlightened his father with the meaning of "Om." Impressed and humbled, Shiva listened like a student to a teacher. This act earned Muruga the name "Swaminatha Swami," meaning "The Teacher of Lord Shiva."

